# Android Shared element transition not working properly as expected

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition

I am applying shared element transition on imageview in android using glide. When I click first time on imageview, it works as expected. But when I click 2nd time, the animation is not as it was first time. It starts from bottom right and expands, Please see image gif for detailed animation.
Also I want to squeeze image when returning back with shared element transition from large image. Currently, it starts from top left and goes to original position.

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1000">
<changeTransform />
<changeClipBounds />
<changeBounds />
<changeImageTransform />
</transitionSet>
```

[image: Shared element transition]